# Is Dr Stone: Ryuusui canon?

Tags: dr.stone

So another animated Dr. Stone segment is out, it's called Dr Stone Ryuusui. It is 55 minutes long, in some places they call it special, though it's larger than an usual special, but shorter than an usual movie.

What I'm interested to know if this new animation is canon, or it isnt part of the main continuity.

Is Dr Stone: Ryuusui canon?

Comment: It's officially called "Television Special" in Japan, so AFAIK it's not based on the manga. Still not sure whether it's canon or not (I don't follow the series).

Comment: [Synopsis says it serve as a bridge between the second and third season.](https://myanimelist.net/anime/50612/Dr_Stone__Ryuusui?q=Dr%20stone%20ry&cat=anime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The special only covers content that you can see in the manga, but some scenes may be slightly altered (nothing too major though, all important plot points are shown as they appear in the source material). If I remember correctly, it leaves off at about chapter 89 of the manga, where the crew of the hot air balloon arrive safely at Ishigami Village.